# Vue 3: Composition API, how to call a method from the component instance?

Tags: typescript, api, vue.js, vuejs3, composition

In Vue 2 i do like this:

```
import Component from '@/components/Component.vue';

    const VueComponent = {
      install(Vue, settings = {}) {
        const Constructor = Vue.extend(Component);
        const ComponentContainer = new Constructor();
    
        ComponentContainer._props = Object.assign(ComponentContainer._props, settings);
        const vm = ComponentContainer.$mount();
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(vm.$el);
       }
    }
```

And then i can call any component method like this:

```
ComponentContainer.add();
```

I'm trying to make my component using Vue 3, TS and Composition API, so i do this:

```
import { App, createApp, Component } from 'vue';
import ComponentName from './components/ComponentName.vue';

const VueComponentName: Component = {
  install(Vue: App, settings = {}) {
    const ComponentContainer = createApp(ComponentName);
    ComponentContainer._component.props = Object.assign(ComponentContainer._component.props, settings);

    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    const vm = ComponentContainer.mount(wrapper);
    document.body.appendChild(vm.$el);
  },
};
```

And in component i create method `add`:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ComponentName',
  setup(props, {}) {
    const add = (status) => {
      console.log('test')
    };

    return { add };
  },
});
</script>
```

Now i want to use component method from the plugin:

```
ComponentContainer.add();
```

But can't do it, the component instance doesn't have this method... What am i do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

> Note: I'm not sure why you're doing all this stuff, it looks a bit dark and overcomplicated for a vue component!

In Vue 3, everything declared within the `setup` method is private to the component. If you want an external component / js code to access some of its properties, you have to explicitly declare it using the [`defineExpose`](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineexpose) composable.

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    function add() {...}

    defineExpose({ add })

    return { add }
  }
}
```

It also exists when using option api: [`expose`](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#expose)